# why No new messages seen in ksql even messages exist?

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb, confluent-control-center

I create table in ksql like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS_T (id BIGINT, product VARCHAR, quantity BIGINT, price BIGINT)
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='orders', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

In kafka I ve "orders" topic

And when I select query tab in ksql even total messages exists , panel says  `No new messages` 
like below

[image]

So how can I solve this? I want to see results like this example in [confluent.io](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html)

AND if I do not use `EMIT CHANGES` it gives this error:

```
Table 'MYTABLE' is not materialized. Refer to https://cnfl.io/queries for info on query types. If you..
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any errors in the KSQL server log? Does the query work if you run it from the KSQL command line interface?

Comment: See also https://www.confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1/

Comment: I did not check commandline and logs , how can Ifind logs?

Comment: How are you running Confluent Platform? Are you using Docker? Or just bare metal?

Comment: I run it on ubuntu and not docker

Comment: did you install from tar/zip or from `.deb` ?

Comment: i instal it from tar/zip

Comment: @RobinMoffatt ı TRied it from ksql command line but it does not worj

Comment: have a look at http://confluent.io/blog/troubleshooting-ksql-part-1. If you're still stuck head to http://cnfl.io/slack and #ksqldb channel - this back & forth isn't so suited to StackOverflow

Comment: The most likely cause is deserialization errors.  Look in the processing_log (Select * from processing_log), the server logs, or you can also look at the error count in the output of DESCRIBE EXTENDED ORDERS_T.  We may be able to help more if you provide an example source message.